# Using ArcPy to add polygon to FeatureClass?

Tags: arcpy, typeerror

I want to convert some poins to polygon and then  add the polygon to feature class. 
but this does not work.where this code is wrong.

```
import arcpy
array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 0),
                  arcpy.Point(0, 1000),
                  arcpy.Point(1000, 1000),
                  arcpy.Point(1000, 0)
                  ])
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
FC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory","Mylayer","POLYGON","","DISABLE   D","DISABLED")
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(FC,("Shape@")) as iCur:
     iCur.insertRow(polygon)

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: argument must be sequence of values
```

Comment: I think I must set  spatialReference for the  polygon

Answer (score 2):

See [Polygon example](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/classes/polygon.htm) at the bottom of the help page for correct syntax for the Polygon class and the same for the [InsertCursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm).

```
import arcpy
array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(0, 0),
                     arcpy.Point(0, 1000),
                     arcpy.Point(1000, 1000),
                     arcpy.Point(1000, 0)
                     ])
polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)

FC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(out_path='in_memory', out_name='Polygon', 
                                        geometry_type='POLYGON')

icur = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(FC,'SHAPE@')
icur.insertRow([polygon])
del icur
```